# How to show div, if one of the checkboxes is checked (with a different name on each checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show div if one of the two checkboxes is checked. I found it in some article but with the same name, I am using a different name for each checkbox to store it into mysql. My current javascript code is

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(jj) {
  function jj() {
    if ((document.getElementById('jj1_ikk').checked) || (document.getElementById('jj2_ikk').checked)) {
      document.getElementById('jsa').style.display="block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('jsa').style.display="none";
    }
  }
})
```

the input fields are

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jj1_ikk" name="jj1_ikk" /><label for="jj1_ikk">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="jj2_ikk" name="jj2_ikk" /><label for="jj2_ikk">B</label>
```

where jj1_ikk and jj2_ikk are the checkboxes id, and jsa is the div that I want to do show/hide.

I hope my description is clear, thank you.

Comment: Please post a working example using code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put two check box in span and check changes onclick span like this

### HTML

```
<span onclick="CheckChanges()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="jj1_ikk" name="jj1_ikk" /><label for="jj1_ikk">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="jj2_ikk" name="jj2_ikk" /><label for="jj2_ikk">B</label>
</span>

<div id="jsa">This is the element that will be shown if both checkboxes aren't checked</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var aCheckBox = document.getElementById("jj1_ikk")
var bCheckBox = document.getElementById("jj2_ikk")

function CheckChanges() {
    if (aCheckBox.checked == true || bCheckBox.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("jsa").style.display = "block"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("jsa").style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake when adding the handler for the change event defining two nested functions. Plus I added the event handler only once the document was loaded. You can test the code in this snippet:

```js
//when the document has been loaded, adds the event handlers to the checkboxes
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.addEventListener('change', () => addHandlers());
});

/**
 * Adds handler for the change event on both checkboxes
 */
function addHandlers(){
    let jj1 = document.getElementById('jj1_ikk');
    let jj2 = document.getElementById('jj2_ikk');

    jj1.addEventListener('change', updateMsgVisibility);
    jj2.addEventListener('change', updateMsgVisibility);
}

/**
 * Show/Hide #jsa based on checkboxes status
 */
function updateMsgVisibility(){

    let jj1 = document.getElementById('jj1_ikk');
    let jj2 = document.getElementById('jj2_ikk');

    if ( (jj1 && (jj1.checked)) || (jj2 && (jj2.checked)) ) {
        document.getElementById('jsa').style.display="block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('jsa').style.display="none";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="jj1_ikk" name="jj1_ikk" /><label for="jj1_ikk">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="jj2_ikk" name="jj2_ikk" /><label for="jj2_ikk">B</label>

<div id="jsa" style="display:none;">This is the element that will be shown if both checkboxes aren't checked</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, It worked but I must click on the checkbox 2 times (on - off - on again) to make it works when the first time the page opened

Comment: the div message starts being hidden now... the only issue here is that getElementById() on the checkbox fails to catch the element at first try for some strange reason. It's totally nonsense like if there's some other element with the same id anywhere on the page. The demo should work